# How do I temporarily remove a Côr WiFi thermostat by Carrier to repair a plaster wall?

Tags: thermostat, carrier

The model number is TP-WEM01-A, installed with the "large backplate", as pictured below.

There are no visible screws, etc. I have the manual but it is no help.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thermostat is simply pressed onto the mounting bracket and "snaps" into place.

See the [installation guide](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/2b/2b0d8011-6432-4799-9a6b-261bbe777fa0.pdf) or [Carrier's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcH4pP9cWLc); at ~2:20, it shows the thermostat being mounted.

Since there is no description for removal, I'd try prying *gently* along the four edges, between thermostat and wall.

BTW, the [owner's manual](https://dms.hvacpartners.com/docs/1009/Public/02/OM-TPWEM-01.pdf) omits mounting the device.